# Angular - Can't import a component from a library

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript

I'm learning Angular and I decided to create separate generic elements in addition to the main project (in a library) and then import and use them according to my needs.
My problem is due to the fact that I can't import the generic components now... (I can import the Module from the library, but when I try to use my component's selector, Angular warns that the element is unknown to it and doesn't compile the server ).

Generic Component:

(.html)

```
<p>f-base-screen works!</p>
```

(.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'nx-flow-base-screen',
  templateUrl: './f-base-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./f-base-screen.component.scss'],
})
export class FBaseScreenComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Library Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FBaseScreenComponent } from './f-base-screen/f-base-screen.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    FBaseScreenComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    FBaseScreenComponent
  ],
})
export class FLibrariesModule {}
```

f-libraries.ts (exports the module and its components):

```
export * from './f-libraries.module';
export * from './f-base-screen/f-base-screen.component';
```

My SharedModule (it's later imported into my app.module):

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FLibrariesModule } from "@nx-flow/f-libraries";

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FLibrariesModule],
    exports: [CommonModule, FLibrariesModule],
    providers: []
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FRestService } from './shared/utils/rest.service';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, SharedModule],
  exports: [],
  providers: [FRestService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My Home.component.module.ts (which imports the SharedModule to use the nx-flow-base-screen component):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { WelcomeService } from '../../shared/services/flow-services/welcome.service';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { FRestService } from '../../shared/utils/rest.service';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [SharedModule],
  providers: [WelcomeService, FRestService],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent],
})
export class HomeComponentModule {}
```

My Home.component.html (using the component, the error that appears in the image is the same as angular throws when I compile):

```
<div>
    <span>Home Page</span>
</div>
<nx-flow-base-screen></nx-flow-base-screen>
```

I already researched and followed tutorials, none of them worked so far. Are there any changes I still need to make to be able to use my component, from the library, within my main project?
If any more files are needed to reach a conclusion, I'll post a print of it.

Error:

> apps/flow/src/app/views/home/home.component.html:4:3 - error
> NG8001: 'nx-flow-base-screen' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'nx-flow-base-screen' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'nx-flow-base-screen' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.

Comment: Hi! Welcome. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: As posted, code should work. Only thing that looks off is bootstrapping both AppComponent and HomeComponent. (May be possible but mostly would expect only one bootstrapped component)

Comment: @AndrewAllen hadn't paid attention to that! The error I got persists even with this code:

Error: apps/flow/src/app/views/home/home.component.html:5:1 - error NG8001: 'nx-flow-base-screen' is not a known element:
1. If 'nx-flow-base-screen' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nx-flow-base-screen' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: please use a service like stackblitz or codesandbox to create a minimal reproducible snippet